# How can I change a Boolean property in Lit-Element to hide content on my component?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, lit-element

I have a custom component that should hide content when I set a boolean property to false. Every other property gets reflected except that one. I must be doing something wrong.

```
static get properties(){
      title: {
        type: String,
        attribute: 'title',
      },

      titleEnable: {
        type: Boolean,
        attribute: 'title-enable',
      },
}

constructor() {
    super();
    this.titleEnable=true;
    this.title="default";
}

render(){

    return html`                
        ${this.titleEnable 
        ? html`
        <p class="title" ?hidden="${!this.titleEnable}">${this.title}</p>
        `
        : html ``} 
    ` 
}
```

If I use that component like `<my-component></my-component>` in an HTML file it shows: default as expected.

If I use it like this: `<my-component title="New Title"></my-component>` it displays: New Title as expected.

BUT if I try to hide it `<my-component title-enable="false"></my-component>` the boolean just doesn't change. I've tried !title-enable, title-enable='false", .titleEnable=false and all the variants you can imagine. What pisses me the most is that whenever I set in the constructor 'this.titleEnable=false' and I happen to just declare the variable WITHOUT value on the tag and it takes it as TRUE an "default" appears. `<my-component title-enable></my-component>` I am completely lost.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, this is a tricky one. You need to handle it differently by passing some object as below:

```
  static get properties() {
    return {
      titleConfig: {
        type: Object,
        attribute: 'title-config'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`                
      ${this.titleConfig.titleEnable
        ? html`
      <p class="title" ?hidden="${!this.titleConfig.titleEnable}">${this.titleConfig.title}</p>
      `
        : html``} 
  `
  }
```

In **HTML**:

```
<my-component title-config='{"title":"shan", "titleEnable": false}'></my-component>
```

Now, the question is why it is `true` every time?

> **Answer:** For a Boolean property to be configurable from markup, it must default to false. If it defaults to true, you cannot set it to false from markup, since the presence of the attribute, with or without a value, equates to true. This is the standard behavior for attributes in the web platform.

It is taken from [polymer doc](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configuring-boolean-properties).

*So, by creating an attribute `title-enable`, the `HTML` considers this attribute as `true`*

It's really a bummer for someone who starts working on Polymer or LitElement .

Comment: What's really a bummer is that this information is not in the lit documentation lol. You are golden bro. A thousand kudos to you.

Comment: _Boolean properties are set by the presence of the attribute, not the attribute value. For the following show is true `<boolean-test show></boolean-test>` and `<boolean-test show="false"></boolean-test>`.  For the following show is false `<boolean-test></boolean-test>`. This does however mean that the default value for boolean properties can't be `true` or you can never set it to `false` with an attribute. So instead of `show` with a default of `true` you would use the opposite with something like `hide` with a default value of `false`._ From: https://github.com/lit/lit-element/issues/948

Answer (score 8):

According to the [documentation](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates):

To bind to a boolean attribute you need to use the "?", notation:

Bind prop3 to a boolean attribute:

```
html`<input type="text" ?disabled="${this.prop3}">`
```

Boolean attributes are added if the expression evaluates to a truthy value, and removed if it evaluates to a falsy value.

Comment: Came back to this to try other solutions. This one doesn't work.

Comment: "If the default value is `true` it'll always be true" holds true!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [reflected attributes](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#reflected-attributes) instead:

```
static get properties(){
      title: {
        type: String,
        attribute: 'title',
      },

      titleEnable: {
        reflect: true,
      },
}

constructor() {
    super();
    this.titleEnable='true';
    this.title="default";
}

handleHidden() {
  return this.titleEnable === 'true'
}

render(){

    return html`                
        ${this.titleEnable 
        ? html`
        <p class="title" ?hidden="${!this.handleHidden()}">${this.title}</p>
        `
        : html ``} 
    ` 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of data type. In lit-element 'false' | 'true' the type is returned as 'string' data type.

Solution:

```
Before that check your attribute data type is string or boolean

     ex: typeof attr

If it return string means, you have two solution:
    1. Change the attributes date type as boolean ex: Boolean(attr).
    2. Consider the value as string and check your condition.

From your example 
    if(this.titleConfig.titleEnable == 'true'){
        //true statement
    }else{
        // false statement
    }
```

my suggestion is this.titleConfig.titleEnable == 'true'

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing your value as an attribute you also could pass it as a property (https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#property-expressions):

```
<my-component .title-enable=${false}></my-component>
```