# Pass a boolean value to a Lit Component

Tags: typescript, lit

I want to pass a boolean value (true/false) to a lit component via. the dom.
I'm having issues because it is always converted to true, I cant seem to find a good example for this in the lit documentation.

So basically:

```
<my-element foo="false" />
...
  @property({type: Boolean})
  foo: boolean;
```

What I tried allready is try to pass: `"${false}"`

[I created a lit playground link with an example here](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gIDxzY3JpcHQgdHlwZT1cIm1vZHVsZVwiIHNyYz1cIi4vc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nLmpzXCI-PC9zY3JpcHQ-XG48L2hlYWQ-XG48Ym9keT5cbiAgPHNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZyBmb289XCJmYWxzZVwiPjwvc2ltcGxlLWdyZWV0aW5nPlxuPC9ib2R5PlxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoicGFja2FnZS5qc29uIiwiY29udGVudCI6IntcbiAgXCJkZXBlbmRlbmNpZXNcIjoge1xuICAgIFwibGl0XCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJAbGl0L3JlYWN0aXZlLWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMS4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjMuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtaHRtbFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiXG4gIH1cbn0iLCJoaWRkZW4iOnRydWV9XQ)

Comment: Can you wrap it in some object as in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60678891/how-can-i-change-a-boolean-property-in-lit-element-to-hide-content-on-my-compone)?

Comment: I mean yes I could but I was hoping for a "cleaner" way of doing this, but thanks for the workarround :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, boolean attributes are dictated by whether they are present or not, not by the string value.

You should simply omit the attribute:

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

And [default the property to false](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#boolean-attributes):

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @property({type: Boolean})
  foo: boolean = false;
}
```

If you're writing markup within lit-html templates, you can use the [boolean attribute expression](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#boolean-attribute-expressions).

```js
let foo = false;
html`<my-element ?foo=${foo}></my-element>`;
```

Comment: thanks I was missing the false as default value